# Server infected by recent cryptojacking malware but different (?) entry point

Tags: exim, malware, reporting, vulnerabilities

One of my servers has been infected by [this cryptojacking malware](https://www.lacework.com/cryptojacking-malware-creative-names/) (reporting to the very same IP than in the article).

[It seems known](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/bknurg/is_is_exploit_or_what/) for this malware to propagate through some Confluence vulnerabilities, however **my server doesn't run Confluence**, and the process was actually owned by `root`, so the entry point is different.

Is this malware already associated to other software vulnerabilities ?  (I couldn't find any.)  Are there guidelines to find what could have been the entry point ?  Should I report this issue anywhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

The script attempts to create a `cloud_agent.service` service under `/etc/systemd/system/`.  The last modification of this file dates June 15th, 22:03, and the file is owned by `root:Debian-exim`, which indicates that the entry point was Exim.

The Exim logs show [an attempt to exploit a recently identified Exim vulnerability](https://serverfault.com/questions/971654) at the very same date and hour, and the code injection resolves to the very same IP.

So this malware was definitely installed through [this Exim vulnerability](https://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2019/06/06/1).